# What is the difference between "migas" and "migajas"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

### English

According to the RAE, both *[miga](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PDtkw27%7CPDw6GsO)* and *[migaja](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PDxayFl)* refer to small bits of bread.  It also suggests that *migaja* is simply a diminuitive of *miga*.  But this doesn't quite line up with my experience:

- A friend from Venezuela told me that one difference is that a child might have *migas* on his face that need to be wiped off, but that when we vacuum the floor, we collect the *migajas*.
- In one of his books, [Juan Villoro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Villoro) (from Mexico) uses the word "migajas" 12 times, but never "migas," when talking about someone's sloppy eating habits ("tirar migajas") as well as the need to clean floors ("Ella es cocinera, lavandera y especialista en recoger migajas")

Thus I wonder: Are there general guidelines for when one of these words is preferred over the other?  And are there regional differences in the use of these words?

---

### Español

Según RAE, tanto *[miga](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PDtkw27%7CPDw6GsO)* como *[migaja](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PDxayFl)* refieren a pedazos pequeños de pan.  También indica que *migaja* es un diminutivo de miga.  Pero eso no se alinea con mi experiencia:

- Una amiga de Venezuela me dijo que una diferencia es que un niño puede tener *migas* en su cara que alguien necesita limpiar, pero que cuando aspiramos el piso, recogemos las *migajas*
- En uno de sus libros, [Juan Villoro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Villoro) (de México) usa la palabra *migajas* 12 veces, pero nunca *migas*, cuando habla de la mala costumbre en comer ("tirar migajas") y también en cuanto a la necesidad de barrer el piso ("Ella es cocinera, lavandera y especialista en recoger migajas")

Por eso me pregunto: ¿Hay reglas generales que indiquen cuando es mejor usar una de estas palabras o la otra?  Y ¿hay diferencias regionales en el uso de estas palabras?

<sup>¡Por favor, no duden en corregir mi traducción al español!</sup>

Comment: There are indeed regional differences but I'm not sure anyone here can summarize them. In Argentina we only say *migas*, in Mexico it would seem they only say *migajas*.

Comment: En España siempre se habla de _migas_, menos cuando se utiliza en sentido abstracto que decimos _migajas_ (_ese ciclista lo ganaba todo, no dejaba ni las migajas_).

Comment: In Colombia _migas_ are bigger like when you split the bread with you fingers by pinching it. That process of getting little pieces of bread has the by product of very tiny particles that are the _migajas_ that usually end up on the table or on the floor. The _migas_ you eat but the _migajas_ are too tiny to do it. I'm not sure if this is clear. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Personalmente, pienso que "migajas" es más un **despectivo** que un diminutivo. Lo que ocurre, a mi juicio, es que las migas se caracterizan por ser pequeñas, así que si son minúsculas son todavía peores. Entonces, que migajas pueda significar "migas más pequeñas" ("diminutivo") es más bien consecuencia de ser un despectivo.

Como bien apunta @ukemi, `migas` se usa poco, al menos en España, excepto para el plato tradicional (que por cierto recomiendo, aunque llena rápidamente el estómago). Sí es frecuente el singular `miga`. La miga del pan es la parte blanda del interior, lo que no es corteza.

Por su parte, `migajas` significa "los restos", pero se caracteriza por ser "demasiado poco". Una persona que piense: `yo me quedo solamente con las migajas` probablemente se sienta muy ofendida, ya que cree injusto que le toque mucha menos cantidad de lo que le corresponde.

Más aún, las migajas son **lo que sobra de otros**, es decir, **lo que los demás se han dejado**, bien porque no quieren, bien porque ya no pueden más y por eso sobra. En ese sentido, "migaja" es profundamente despectivo, ya que

- Es lo que otros no han querido. Otros lo desprecian, y sin embargo para ti es lo único que queda. Solamente te queda lo que otros desprecian.
- O bien es lo que ha sobrado de los otros; pero, si sobra, sigue dando a entender que, si los demás volvieran a querer, volverían a ser para ellos y tú te quedarías sin nada. Eso te relega a un papel totalmente secundario, lo cual es un gran desprecio.

Comment: Si viene de *miga + -aja* sí es un despectivo, sin embargo puede ser que viene del diminutivo de la palabra latina *mica > [\*micalia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/migaja#Etymology) > ... > migaja* (cf. pt. *migalha*, gl. *migalla*). Las primeras entradas del CORDE por *migaja* son muy antiguos (1240-1250), siglos más antiguos que las de otras palabras sufijadas con *-ajo* que he buscado.

Answer (score 1):

Since my comment has a few votes already I'll make it into an answer.

In Colombia *migas* are bigger like when you split the bread with you fingers by pinching it.

The process of getting little pieces of bread has the by product of very tiny particles that are the *migajas* that usually end up on the table or on the floor.

The *migas* you eat but the *migajas* are too tiny to do it.

So the main difference between them, for us, is the size which is obvious since *migajas* is the diminutive of *migas*

Answer (score 0):

Others may better be able to detail the regional differences and preferences for *miga* vs *migaja* in different contexts, but as plural words they have distinct secondary meanings (the final definitions mentioned in their respective DLE entries):

- *migajas* = leftovers
- [*migas*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Migas) = a dish made from leftover bread

[image]

Comment: Right – I realize that they have those meanings, and that there's also some variance in how they are used in set phrases and figuratively.  I'm more curious about the "small bits of bread" meaning.